# How do I follow DRY in Java object setter?

Tags: java, dry

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class parent {
}

public class child1 extends parent {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  // getter & setter
}

public class child2 extends parent {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  // getter & setter
}

public class demo {
  public child1 copytoc1(Map m, child1 c) {
    c.setid(m.get("id"));
    c.setName(m.get("name"));
  }

  public child2 copytoc2(Map m, child2 c) {
    c.setid(m.get("id"));
    c.setName(m.get("name"));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
        demo d =new demo();
        Map m=new HashMap();
        m.set("id","1");
        m.set("name","1name");
        d.copytoc1(m,new child1);
        m.set("id","2");
        m.set("name","2name");
        d.copytoc1(m,new child2);
  }
}
```

I want to avoid `copytoc1` and `copytoc2` methods which are tied object type want to write generic copy method something like `public T copy(Map m, T t)` but cannot make it work. Simply how to avoid DRY here.

Note:I am using jdk7

Comment: Your code doesn't seem valid, don't think it compiles (Your copy methods don't return anything).  Please post valid code to begin with.

Comment: Its a design question , I want to avoid d.copytooc1 ()  d.copytooc2 () whcih are eseentialy same code block .i want to avoid the same repetetive code.

Answer (score 2):

You won't repeat yourself by **not having different classes for different children**.

A class is a **type** of an object. You can have more children by having *multiple instances* of one type of child.

Here's a version of your code that compiles and does what it seems you want to do:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {
  public static class parent {
  }

  public static class child {
    private String id;
    private String name;
  }

  public void copyToChild(Map<String, String> m, child c) {
    c.id = m.get("id");
    c.name = m.get("name");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Demo d = new Demo();
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("id", "1");
    m.put("name", "1name");
    d.copyToChild(m, new child());
    m.put("id", "2");
    m.put("name", "2name");
    d.copyToChild(m, new child());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example `child1` and `child2`should be childres of a more generic class.

There you could implement the common sets, and in each children the specifics. So then, when you want to do copytoc1, you would do:

```
public child1 copytoc1(Map m, child1 c) {
    copytoc(m,c); //a parent method.
    // especific methods:
    c.setName(m.get("name"))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep both child1 and child2 but move the variables into the parent as they are the same variables

```
public class demo {
    static class parent {
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    static class child1 extends parent {

    }

    static class child2 extends parent {

        // getter & setter
    }

    public parent copy(Map m, parent c) {
        c.setId((String) m.get("id"));
        c.setName((String) m.get("name"));
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        demo d = new demo();
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("id", "1");
        m.put("name", "1name");
        child1 c1 = new child1();
        d.copy(m, c1);
        m.put("id", "2");
        m.put("name", "2name");
        parent p = d.copy(m, new child2());
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```